# Difference between path and value attributes in @RequestMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

What is the difference between below two attributes and which one to use when?

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/usr/{userId}")
public String findDBUserGetMapping(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
  return "Test User";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/usr/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findDBUserReqMapping(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
  return "Test User";
}
```

Comment: According to the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--), they're the same : 
"This is an alias for path(). For example @RequestMapping("/foo") is equivalent to @RequestMapping(path="/foo"). "

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments (and [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--)), `value` is an alias to `path`. Spring often declares the `value` element as an alias to a commonly used element. In the case of `@RequestMapping` (and `@GetMapping`, ...) this is the `path` property:

> This is an alias for [`path()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--). For example `@RequestMapping("/foo")` is equivalent to `@RequestMapping(path="/foo")`.

The reasoning behind this is that the `value` element is the default when it comes to annotations, so it allows you to write code in a more concise way.

Other examples of this are:

- `@RequestParam` (`value` → `name`)
- `@PathVariable` (`value` → `name`)
- ...

However, aliases aren't limited to annotation elements only, because as you demonstrated in your example, `@GetMapping` is an alias for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET`).

Just looking for [references of `AliasFor` in their code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/search?&q=AliasFor&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) allows you to see that they do this quite often.

Answer (score 20):

`@GetMapping` is a shorthand for `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

In your case.
`@GetMapping(path = "/usr/{userId}")` is a shorthand for `@RequestMapping(value = "/usr/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

Both are equivalent. Prefer using shorthand `@GetMapping` over the more verbose alternative. One thing that you can do with `@RequestMapping` which you can't with `@GetMapping` is to provide multiple request methods.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT)
public void handleRequet() {

}
```

Use `@RequestMapping` when you need to provide multiple Http verbs.

Another usage of `@RequestMapping` is when you need to provide a top level path for a controller. For e.g.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping
    public void createUser(Request request) {
        // POST /users
        // create a user
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Users getUsers(Request request) {
        // GET /users
        // get users
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Users getUserById(@PathVariable long id) {
        // GET /users/1
        // get user by id
    }
}
```

Comment: @Juzer Ali `@GetMapping(path = "/usr/{userId}")`, `@GetMapping(value = "/usr/{userId}")` and `@GetMapping("/usr/{userId}")` all are same?

Answer (score 8):

[@GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#path--) is an alias for @RequestMapping

> @GetMapping is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET).

[value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#value--) method is an alias for path method.

> This is an alias for path(). For example @RequestMapping("/foo") is equivalent to @RequestMapping(path="/foo").

So both methods are similar in that sense.

Comment: The first one is "@GetMapping", not a "@RequestMapping"