# Comparison: usage of @RequestMapping vs @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

I would like to know which one of the above are better/correct/most_used or what. The first, using value in the @RequestMapping or the other using path.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/isbn/{isbnCode}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> findByIsbnCode(@PathVariable String isbnCode) {
        Book obj = service.findByIsbnCode(isbnCode);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
    }
// Request: http://localhost:8080/books/title?title=book_title

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = { "/title" })
    public ResponseEntity<?> findByTitle(@RequestParam(value = "title") String title) {
        Book obj = service.findByTitle(title);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
    }
// Request: http://localhost:8080/books/isbn/978-84-663-4612-2
```

Both works. Just wanna find out the differences between the two.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50351590/difference-between-path-and-value-attributes-in-requestmapping-annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"URI parameter (Path Param/variable denoted by @PathVariable) is basically used to identify a specific resource or resources whereas Query Parameter(or request param denoted by @RequestParam) is used to sort/filter those resources."
The first example makes use of path variable, here you are extracting value from the url itself, whereas in second example you are fetching a request/query parameter.
References:
https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-the-uri-param-and-query-param-with-r
[https://blog.restcase.com/7-rules-for-rest-api-uri-design/#:~:text=URIs%20should%20follow%20a%20predictable,APIs%20are%20written%20for%20consumers](https://blog.restcase.com/7-rules-for-rest-api-uri-design/#:%7E:text=URIs%20should%20follow%20a%20predictable,APIs%20are%20written%20for%20consumers).

Answer (score 1):

[JPA](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) is the Java Persistence API, and it has nothing to do with [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html);

You are asking about the difference(s) between `path` and `value` of the @RequestMapping:

> Just wanna find out the differences between the two.

`path` and `value` elements are aliases for each other, and there are only minor differences I can see from the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html):

When using `path`:

- Ant-style path patterns are also supported (e.g. `"/profile/**"`);
- Placeholders (e.g. `"/${profile_path}"`) can be used.